# Hidden Markov Model: Proving E2 independent of E4 given X3

Tags: hidden-markov-model

In a first order HMM (each state only depends on the previous state, and each observation $O_i$ only depend on the current state $X_i$), I want to show that $E_2\perp E_4 | X_3$. Here's a proof given by my professor:
[image]

I understand everything until the transition here:

[image]

Why does this hold? It looks like this: $\sum_{x,y} f(X)g(Y) = \sum_{x}f(x) \cdot \sum_{y}g(Y)$. This looks obviously not true to me, or I may be misunderstanding somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Nonintuitive, perhaps, but true nonetheless!  Try writing it out explicitly with three terms in each sum: $(x_1+x_2+x_3)(y_1+y_2+y_3) = x_1y_1 +  x_1y_2 + x_1y_3 + x_2y_1 \dots + x_3y_3$, and you'll see that it works.

Comment: You're so right! I can't believe how I didn't see this fact. Thanks.